# viewDidAppear presence in code messes with layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, layout, viewdidappear

I have encountered some seriously odd situation.

I have a code looking like this:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning]; 
}
```

with the view controller looking like this:
[image: OK state]

Strangely enough, when I **ONLY ADD**

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
}
```

even **WITHOUT** any action inside, it totally messes up with the layout of the view controller and makes it look like this:
[image: KO state]

**I have not added any other line of code then just empty header for viewDidAppear. When deleted, the layout is OK.** What the heck is happening here?

Comment: What happens if you call `[super viewDidAppear:animated];` from within viewDidAppear:?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your view will change size after viewDidLoad with regard to the status bar and navigation bar (if you have them). If you don't call `[super viewDidAppear:animated];`, your subviews may not be repositioned properly.