# Consequences of not calling super in viewWill and viewDid methods

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

There are places in my app where I've overridden `viewWillAppear`, `viewWillDisappear`, etc. without calling `super`.  What are the possible consequences / effects of this?  Can it have effects on application behavior?  I'm tempted to fix many of them, but I'm not sure I have the time to do proper regression testing before my next release.

Comment: Here's one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18536858/viewdidappear-presence-in-code-messes-with-layout

Comment: In my app the consequence was a bug with scroll view. It had the size of the whole screen so the navigation bar and the keyboard overlaps.

Comment: that will loop through the viewWillAppear-watever

Comment: There are very few cases where you should not call `[super someMethod]` when overriding `someMethod` (`UIViewController loadView` is one). You need to add those calls and you need to test. Your app may be behaving in a certain way due to unpredictable results. Fixing your code could break some subtle behavior. But this is better than not fixing your code and having your app suddenly break on the next release of iOS. Do it right now.

Answer (score 3):

The consequences of not calling the super implementation are that things will break in weird and unpredictable ways. You're violating the rules of the framework and basic Object Oriented design, and you should expect problems (as other users have pointed out).