# Prevent TableView from Scrolling When Row Selected

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to prevent my table view from scrolling to the selected cell.

For some reason when I select a cell and the keyboard appears, my cell moves up a bit and I do not want that behavior.

I am using a table view controller and set `isScrollEnabled` to `false`.

I have overridden `didSelectRowAt` to do absolutely nothing.

In the storyboard, I have scrolling disabled, paging disabled, bounce on scroll/zoom disabled, bounce horizontally/vertically disabled.

Yet it still scrolls to the selected cell.

Comment: duplicate of an existing question, see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22447614/how-do-i-stop-a-tableview-from-scrolling-when-the-keyboard-appears and also this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9637089/disabling-automatic-scrolling-of-uitableview-when-editing-uitextfield-inside-uit/12010951#12010951

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use a `UIViewController` with a tableview inside.
The behaviour your are describing is actually something automatically handled by the `UITableViewController`.

EDIT:

Here is a screenshot of a `UIViewController` with a tableview with static cells in it:

[image]

Comment: I'm using static table view cells so I can't use an embedded view controller.  It had to be a table view controller.

Comment: oh you mean you are using a xib? because you can set static cells to a tableview embedded in a UIViewController

Comment: Latest Xcode and Swift version wouldn't allow me to do what you describe.

Comment: Well I use everyday the latest Xcode and latest swift. I can tell you that it's totally possible to create a `UIViewController` in a storyboard with static cells in it. Check my edited answer.

Comment: When I have time I'll look into what the issue was.  Definitely wasn't working for me.

Comment: If it was not working, I'm pretty sure your were working with a .xib instead of a storyboard. In a xib, you can't add any cells in a tableview.

Answer (score 0):

ok, in my whole career as iOS developer, this might be the first case where subclassing UITableView **IS** the best answer!

---

UITableView uses a pan gesture recognizer to detect the scrolling gesture. The tableview itself must be it's delegate, therefore we can stop the gesture from being detected by subclassing UITableView:

```
import UIKit

class DontScrollTableView: UITableView, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
   
    var dontScroll = false
    
    override func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return !dontScroll
    }
}
```

in our UITableViewDelegate implementation we can toggle scrolling:

```
var previouslySelectedIndexPath: IndexPath?

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let tv = tableView as? DontScrollTableView {
        if let lastSelected = previouslySelectedIndexPath {
            tv.dontScroll = lastSelected != indexPath
            if lastSelected == indexPath {
                tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)
                previouslySelectedIndexPath = nil
            } else {
                previouslySelectedIndexPath = indexPath
            }
        } else {
            tv.dontScroll = true
            previouslySelectedIndexPath = indexPath
        }
    }
    
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let tv = tableView as? DontScrollTableView {
        tv.dontScroll = false
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can avoid scrolling tableview simply by using this line of code....

```
tableView.isScrollEnabled = false
```

this line will disable scroll feature for tableview whenever you want it to scroll again set this property to true.

Answer (score -2):

Solution was to override viewwillappear and not call the super method.

Comment: I Won't recommend doing that. You're violating the rules of the framework and basic Object Oriented design, and you should expect problems.

Comment: A good example of what could happen: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18536858/viewdidappear-presence-in-code-messes-with-layout